# How do I and what does it mean to splice this discord,js command code?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, array-splice

I've been working on a discord bot that uses javascript. I found this command online that I wanted to add to it.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("No");
  let botmessage = args.join(" ");
  message.delete().catch();
  message.channel.send(botmessage);
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "say"
}
```

when I say `:say Hello!` or `:say RandomText`, the discord bot should reply with `Hello!`, `RandomText`, etc.

But instead it replies with `:say RandomText`.

to remove `:say` from the reply someone told me I have to splice it at the 1st space, but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: How did you define `args` in your main file?

Comment: @Syntle

**let args = messageArray.slice(1);**

Comment: and how did you define `messageArray`?

Comment: @Syntle I cant find it, here you can look if you want

[glitch.com](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tnaebot)

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming the main file is fine and there's only problems in this file, you can try this (code below). It works fine without async so you can take that away.

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'say',
  execute(message, args) {
  if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("No");
  let botmessage = args.join(" ");
  message.delete().catch();
  message.channel.send(botmessage);
  }
}
```

This should work just fine, but make sure you have a message you want the bot to say the same thing to right after the command (for example, if your prefix is '!', then you need to write something like `!say repeat this` or something). Hope this helps :)